# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: search by ID / search by Class name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im trying to send a message on the website kleinanzeigen.de . To do this I need to open the page and click on the "Nachrichten" Button, then Im inputting the desired message. To do this I wrote a function. But whenever I run it I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url1 = "https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/play-station-3-mit-zubehoer-spiele/2682065144-279-1329"

def first_message(message, url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("-profile")
    options.add_argument(r'C:\Users\Fried\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\bpmt5r5r.default-release')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "send-message-sidebar-logged-in").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    search_form = driver.find_element(By.ID, "message-textarea-input") //error
    time.sleep(1)
    search_form.send_keys(message)
    time.sleep(1)
    search_form.submit()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    quit()
first_message("Guten Tag", url1)
```

I already tried finding the button element with CLASS_NAME and waiting longer before searching for the element.

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the relevant element in the form of text?

Comment: <button data-testid="send-message-sidebar-logged-in" class="jsx-3224015369 jsx-1824725262 Button-secondary"><span class="jsx-2947255534 Button--Body"><div class="jsx-2947255534 Button--Icon-left"><i class="jsx-82572997"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 1.......
Is this what u mean? Im not quite sure how to copy the element

Comment: You may want to target the "data-testid" attribute... something like XPATH of //button[@data-testid='send-message-sidebar-loggin-in']  (You should probably also be using webdriverwaits... explicit with expected conditions: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/